# Thread doesnt stop running even though its found the password in the file

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++

function `void readFile1()` is exactly the same as `void readfile2()` and `void readfile3()`. I just deleted them to make it easier to read. Once I solve it for one of the functions, I can just add it to the rest of the functions, too.

My problem is, whenever I run the code, even if it finds the password, the threads will keep running until all of the passwords in the 3 password files have been checked.  I'm trying to find a way to stop that.

I tried adding a semaphore so it would signal the other threads that one of the threads have found the correct password in the text file it was looking through, telling the other threads to stop. But when I tried implementing that, I was getting lots of errors, and I'm unsure that was the way to go with solving my issue. So, I'm a little stuck as to how to stop the threads!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

//Variables
string password = "";
bool password_not_found_t1 = false; 
bool password_not_found_t2 = false;
bool password_not_found_t3 = false;
bool thread1_working = false; 
bool thread2_working = false;
bool thread3_working = false;

//Functions
void readFile1(string file_name) { 
    thread1_working = true; 
    ifstream file(file_name); 
    if (file.is_open()) { 
        string line;
        bool res = false; 
        while (getline(file, line)) {
        system("cls");
        if (thread1_working && thread2_working && thread3_working) {
            printf("Thread 1 working... \nThread 2 working... \nThread 3 working... \n");
        } else if (thread1_working && thread2_working) {
            printf("Thread 1 working... \nThread 2 working... \n");
        } else if (thread1_working && thread3_working) {
            printf("Thread 1 working... \nThread 3 working... \n");
        } else if (thread2_working && thread3_working) {
            printf("Thread 2 working... \nThread 3 working... \n");
        } else if (thread1_working) {
            printf("Thread 1 working... \n");
        } else if (thread2_working) {
            printf("Thread 2 working... \n");
        } else if (thread3_working) {
            printf("Thread 3 working... \n");
        }

        string text_line = line.c_str(); 

        if (text_line == password) {
            printf("\n\nThe correct password was: %s \nFound on Thread 1\n\n", text_line.c_str()); 
            res = true;
            break;
        }

        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    if (!res) {
        password_not_found_t1 = true;
        
    }
    file.close();
}
if (password_not_found_t1 && password_not_found_t2 && password_not_found_t3) { 
    system("cls");
    printf("Password not found in database.\n\n");
}
thread1_working = false; 
}

int main() {

    ifstream correct_password("correct_password.txt");
    if (correct_password.good()) {
        getline(correct_password, password);
    }
    correct_password.close();


thread t1(readFile1, "password1.txt"); 
thread t2(readFile2, "password2.txt");
thread t3(readFile3, "password3.txt");


t1.join(); 
t2.join();
t3.join();

system("pause");
```

Comment: If `readFile2` and `readFile3` look the same as this, you absolutely need synchronization before accessing those shared variables that get written to by one of the threads. The easy way to do that is to make them `atomic<bool>` instead of `bool`, but consider having something higher-level like a future per thread that you can coordinate in `main` (which eliminates the need for globals). You can also pass `password` into the threads instead of making it global.

Comment: Hack this down to a proper [mre] and you'll probably find your bug. If not, with a MRE there's less to wade through and you're more likely to get a good, well-targeted answer.

Comment: Is there something quicker i could look towards implementing to make it stop looking through the files if it finds the password? Or would i need to get them Synchronised before i could even look into adding signalling?

Comment: Synchronization has to be built in as soon as you start working with threads or you'll never get off the ground.

Comment: Note that if all of the files are on the same disk you'll probably find your program isn't much faster and maybe even slower as the threads fight it out for access to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you thread functions are the same - you don't need multiple copies, just create multiple threads for that same function.

Where you check `while (getline(file, line))`, and another test of the global bool flag `found`, that will be set by any function that finds the password.

Don't call `system("cls");` from each thread; you won't see anything on your screen.